# Perf collect stats

Tags: performancecounter, cpu-architecture, perf

Using perf, is there a standard technique to collect stats (i-cache hit-rate, d-cache hit-rate, LLC hit-rate) at regular intervals of 1 millisecond?

Currently, I am using this command:

```
perf record -e instructions,\
L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-store-misses,\
L1-icache-load-misses,\
LLC-loads,LLC-stores \
-a -F 1000 sleep 1
```

This command collects 1000 samples every second and writes the data to *perf.data* file. I want to read the data stored in this file in this format:

```
Sample1: #i-cache hits #i-cache misses ...
Sample1: #i-cache hits #i-cache misses ...
```

However, *perf report* is showing all kinds of information that I do not need (fraction of time spent in kernel functions).

Is there a way to filter all this information and just focus on the phase information that I need? 
Is there a standard way to identify phases in a program execution?

Comment: `perf stat` doesn't do what you want?

Comment: `perf stat` has an `--interval-print` parameter, but I think the minimum interval is 10 ms.

Comment: Since perf stat writes the data to a file so regularly, I am skeptical about its impact on the benchmark execution. I suppose perf record stores the data in arrays that should make it better suited for small interval analysis, as compared to perf stat

Comment: Try `perf report -D` to see how they are stored; and try `perf script` to get some parseable output. There are [options of perf script](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/Documentation/perf-script.txt) to control which fields to print. `perf record -F1000` and `perf stat -I 1000` are different: `report` reports around 1 kHz instruction pointer sampling for every event; and `stat` just counts all and reports current values every second (for `-I 1000`). `perf stat -I 1` will try to report every 1 ms, try it and measure overhead.